# How can I use Gauss-Legendre cuadrature to solve integral equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

In the book *Numerical methods using MATLAB* (John H. Mathews, Kurtis D. Fink) I found this exercise as part of *Algorithms and Programs* section:
[image]

First of all: what is the meaning of an aproximate solution in this case?

More important: how can I solve it?

and finally, is a general way to solve this kind of integral equation for, lets say
$$v(x)=f(x)+\int_{-1}^{1}U(x,t)v(t)dt$$

Answer (score 3):

Substitute the integral by the Legendre-quadrature with nodes $t_i$ and weights $w_i$, and consider the cases where $x$ equals each of the nodes:

$$\begin{align*} \forall x\in\{t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n\}:\quad
v(x)&=f(x)+\int_{-1}^{1}U(x,t)v(t)dt\\
&\approx f(x)+\sum_{i=1}^n w_iU(x,t_i)v(t_i)
\end{align*}$$

That gives you $n$ linear equations:

$$\begin{align*}\forall j\in [1,n]:\quad
v(t_j)=f(t_j)+\sum_{i=1}^n w_iU(t_j,t_i)v(t_i)
\end{align*}$$

with $n$ unknowns $v(t_1),v(t_2),\ldots,v(t_n)$.

When they are solved, everything but $x$ is known in $\ v(x)\approx f(x)+\sum_{i=1}^n w_iU(x,t_i)v(t_i)\ $

Comment: But for differents $n$ I have different {$t_1,...,t_n$} vor which $v(t_i)$ is exact. Can I use multiples values of $n$ to improve the result?